# How to measure throughput of a network when using skype

Tags: c#, performance, matlab, skype, throughput

I am using USB dongle Wimax and skype  as voip application . I want to measure the throughput (kb/s or Mb/s) at run time . is there any way to do this using matlab or C#? (I have a project and need to write a code not using the already existing tools ) thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you want to write something to do it? If all you want to do is know the information just use Fiddler or some other packet sniffing tool.

Comment: What is the definition of "already existing tool"? Ultimately, you either need to tap into the network stack to obtain the data to count (and the tap/network stack already exists), or you start from some kernel performance counters (which also already exist).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Wireshark. Place a listener and capture some packets. You can view the capture and it'll tell your the bandwidth being used. In C# I'm sure there's a way, but why reinvent the wheel? Use wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

If it is more or less the only app using network - network related perf counters can give you some information. Start with PerfMon to see if you can get information you need, than either continue using it (i.e. dump counters to SQL DB for analysis) or use C# to monitor counters.

Comment: @SaraHoussein, I'm not sure about your comment/edit... At what level code that you need to write should be? If you can't use perf counters (and similarly ETW traces if there are any) than it sounds like you are looking for much lower level like drivers... but for such low lever code you probably should use C/C++ and not C#..